# I wanna check 2 element already in the array

Tags: python

I wanna check 2 elements already in the array.
Now my code is

```
Y = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
if (1 in Y) &(2 in Y):
  print("yes")
else:
  print("no")
```

and I wanna print out yes because [1, 2, 3] of Y has 1&2.But now,it print out no.
For example,if  `if (1 in Y) &(4 in Y):` is my if statement,in that time I wanna print out no because 1&4 are not in same array.
So,I cannot understand why my code does not print out yes.How can I fix this?

Comment: You mean `and`, not `&`. And neither `1` nor `2` are in `Y`. They are, however, in `Y[0]`.

Comment: Maybe you want `if any(1 in x for x in Y) and any(2 in x for x in Y):`? That will check whether `1` and `2` are in any of the elements of `Y`.

Answer (score 3):

The `if X in Y` statement checks `Y` for the existence of `X`. In your code (if we simplify the steps) It checks:

```
X == [1, 2, 3] or X == [4, 5]
```

Since none of those are true the answer is `False`.

If I understood correctly, what you want to do is:

```
flag = False
for item in Y:
    if 1 in item and 2 in item:
        flag = True
        break

print("yes") if flag else print("no")
```

Comment: Thats what the OP wrote in his code so i guess that it is.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) and [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any).

```
>>> rows = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
```

## [1, 2]

```
>>> to_search = [1, 2]
```

### Check that 1 and 2 are in the same sub-list of `Y`

```
>>> any(all(x in row for x in to_search) for row in rows)
True
```

There should be one sublist of `rows` which include every `x` from `to_search`.

### Check that 1 and 2 are in `Y`

```
>>> all(any(x in row for row in rows) for x in to_search)
True
```

Every `x` from the `to_search` list should be in one of the sublists of `rows`.

## [1, 4]

With `[1, 4]`, the difference between the two becomes more apparent. `1` and `4` are both somewhere in `Y`, but not in the same sub-list:

### Check that 1 and 4 are in the same sub-list of `Y`

```
>>> to_search = [1, 4]
>>> any(all(x in row for x in to_search) for row in rows)
False
```

### Check that 1 and 4 are in `Y`

```
>>> all(any(x in row for row in rows) for x in to_search)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this help you?

```
X, Y = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
if 1 in X and 2 in X:
  print("yes")
else:
  print("no")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is not normal a list .. it is a list  of lists. If you want to check you need to check for each item in Y. It should be something like this

```
for list in Y:
    if (1 in list) and (2 in list):
          print("Yes")
          break
else:
     print("No")
```

Comment: Python has `list`s, not `array`s. The code you suggest would print "Yes" only if both elements were found in the same `list`. (Not sure, but my guess is that's not what the original question was asking for.) And the `&` should be `and`.